# What encoding does FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, text) use?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, msdn

`Windows.Storage.FileIo.WriteTextAsync` method has two overloads, with and without text encoding.

However, [MSDN pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileio.writetextasync.aspx) of the method (either the main page or the page for either overload) does not specify what encoding is used by the method without encoding parameter.

So what encoding is used by default?

Additional question: Stuff like this is probably documented *somewhere*. So how to find the relevant information from MSDN? Is it organized according to some pattern I don't see?

Comment: What assembly is the `FileIO` class in?

Comment: @OndrejJanacek It's WinRT, so it's not in a normal assembly.

Comment: @OndrejJanacek Well, added the full namespace to question text. No idea what assembly it is in, other than it is part of Windows 8 and Windows Runtime APIs.

Comment: It is undocumented.  I'm pretty sure this is intentional, WinRT  aggressively addressed the text encoding nightmare.  About time.  The guarantee you have is that you can always reliably read it back with a WinRT program.  If you really do care about the encoding because a non-WinRT program is going to read the file then use the overload that lets you pass the UnicodeEncoding.

Comment: @HansPassant Ok. Assuming no better answer appears (or exists), then I'll accept that if you write it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the overloaded method with encoding parameter:

> Remarks
>
> This method attempts to automatically detect the encoding of a
>   file based on the presence of byte order marks. If an encoding cannot
>   be detected, the encoding specified by the caller is used.

And that is how the first method works just without the last sentence:

> This method attempts to automatically detect the encoding of a
>   file based on the presence of byte order marks.

If an encoding cannot be detected, [Encoding.Default Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.default.aspx) is used.

Comment: Where does it say that `Encoding.Default` will be used? `Encoding.Default` is an ANSI char set - and I really doubt it'd be using that by default for WRT programs!

Comment: Also, that seems a bit strange... This is *writing* a file. If file exists, then I guess it could first be read to determine existing BOM, then overwrite using same encoding, but this seems a bit convoluted. I thought that text in the page was a documentation bug, when I read it, actually...

Comment: What would you assume instead, Matthew?

Comment: @duDE I'd rather not "assume". Also, I am creating this file, and then I'll keep overwriting it, and this document implies, that I can't change the encoding if it is detecteable, unless I go and delete the old file first. Is the API really like this?

Comment: @hyde I think the MSDN documentation may be inaccurate! It certainly wouldn't be the first time. You may have to determine this empirically... I'm guessing the default will be either UTF8 or UTF16 (but probably UTF8)

Comment: Well, +1 for the link to the property documentation anyway

Comment: @hyde: Thank you! +1 for any way very good question done already ;)